# Why won't pd.read_csv accept a variable name within the file path in windows?

Tags: python, windows, spyder, filepath

I'm trying to put a variable name into a file path to open a csv using spyder 5, python 3.7.9, in windows. It worked fine on the raspberry pi and also on Ubuntu but I can't figure out the windows file path conventions. Code below

```
import pandas as pd


#%% 
needle_size = '14mm_'
Pressure = '5mb'
test_var = needle_size+Pressure

prelim = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Edwardtx\Downloads\Tomsstuff\data_pp_kvals\test2\Inner\14mm\'+test_var+'.csv')
```

I get the error of a red circle with a white cross in the middle on the left of the screen and it says

*'EOL while scanning string literal pyflakes E'*

What's also weird to me is that normally the text that can be used as a variable turns black between the plus signs as opposed to being green when it's a string. In the example above .csv is black and the rest is green, why?

Furthermore I've tried adding r before the path and ,'rb' after, separately, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\` in the file path is being mistaken for an escape character. Unfortunately, even raw strings cannot end in a backslash (`\`) character, as the ending quote would still be escaped. Try defining your path and filename separately, then join them with a format string.

```
path = r"C:\Users\Edwardtx\Downloads\Tomsstuff\data_pp_kvals\test2\Inner\14mm"
filename = test_var + ".csv"
file_path = r"%s\%s" % (path, filename)

prelim = pd.read_csv(file_path)
```

Reference: [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

Comment: Thanks for the link Bill, but as I state underneath the code, I've tried making it a raw string, that didn't work. Neither did making it an f-string either. I get the following error

'SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Also, I've edited my answer in case the version of python I'm using is important.

Comment: @TomEdwards You're right. I didn't notice that one of the strings ended in a \ which is still mistaken for an escape. See my updated answer.

Comment: @BilltheLizard `os.path.sep` might be a more flexible option...

Answer (score 2):

`\` is being read as the beginning of an escape sequence. You should use an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) instead:

```
prelim = pd.read_csv(f'C:\Users\Edwardtx\Downloads\Tomsstuff\data_pp_kvals\test2\Inner\14mm\{test_var}.csv')
```

This is of course assuming that you're using Python 3.6+.

You can also change the default `\` Windows path delimiter to `/`:

```
prelim = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Edwardtx/Downloads/Tomsstuff/data_pp_kvals/test2/Inner/14mm/' + test_var + '.csv')
```

This will work just fine, but you have to make sure it's *not* a raw string.

However, the *truly* Pythonic answer is to use [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html). For example:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> test_var = "foo"
>>> base_path = r"C:\Users\Edwardtx\Downloads\Tomsstuff\data_pp_kvals\test2\Inner\14mm"
# note the raw string and lack of trailing \
>>> full_path = os.path.join(base_path, test_var + ".csv")
>>> print(full_path)
'C:\\Users\\Edwardtx\\Downloads\\Tomsstuff\\data_pp_kvals\\test2\\Inner\\14mm\\foo.csv'
```

[`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) joins its arguments with `os.path.sep`, which is system-dependent.

Comment: Thanks MattDMo but as I state underneath the code, I've tried making it a raw string, that didn't work. Neither did making it an f-string either. I get the following error

'SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape 

Also, I've edited my answer in case the version of python I'm using is important.

Comment: @TomEdwards try changing the ``\``s to `/`s. The reason you're getting the Unicode error is because `\UXXXXXXXX` is a Python escape code for Unicode codepoints. It's trying to interpret `\Users\Edwa` as hex, and failing. Windows Python handles filepaths with `/` delimiters in them just fine. The other option to change all ``\`` delimiters to ``\\``.

Comment: I switched all the all \ delimiters to \\ got the following error. 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\\\Users\\\\Edwardtx\\\\Downloads\\\\Tomsstuff\\\\data_pp_kvals\\\\test2\\\\Inner\\\\14mm\\\\14mm_5mb_.csv'

What is going on??

Also tried using \s to /s and got an invalid syntax error....

Comment: @TomEdwards The path should either be `C:/Users/Edwardtx/Downloads/Tomsstuff/data_pp_kvals/test2/Inner/14mm/' + test_var + '.csv'` or `'C:\\Users\\Edwardtx\\Downloads\\Tomsstuff\\data_pp_kvals\\test2\\Inner\\14mm\\' + test_var + '.csv'`

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear in my comment but I tried both replacements MattDMo, neither worked. 

The double backslash is interpreted as four times backslash as it says in the error.

Comment: @TomEdwards check out the `os` module, especially [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html). Using `os.path.sep` will solve lots of problems. I'll edit my answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the following way using an f-string to read the CSV files

example:

```
import pandas as pd


#%% 
needle_size = '14mm_'
Pressure = '5mb'
test_var = needle_size+Pressure

prelim = pd.read_csv(f'C:\Users\Edwardtx\Downloads\Tomsstuff\data_pp_kvals\test2\Inner\14mm\{test_var}.csv')
```